How can I display a GLTF File using Qwik and Three Js?
I have this current code setup in the qwik js framework to display a gltf file inside of my website using three js, but for whatever reason it simply doesn't display it. There are no error logs or anything either. Are there any nuances for qwik or react that I'm not using? I read on the docs for qwik that in order to use three js efficiently one can have a react component and use it within there. It's what I tried with this code, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
// ThreeJSScene.jsx
/** @jsxImportSource react */
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { qwikify$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-react';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

import * as THREE from 'three';

const ThreeJSScene = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(4, 5, 11);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 32, 32);
    groundGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
    const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 0x555555,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
    scene.add(groundMesh);

    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 3, 100, 0.2, 0.5);
    spotLight.position.set(0, 25, 0);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('frontend/public');
    loader.load('bane10-20.gltf', (gltf) => {
      const mesh = gltf.scene;
      mesh.position.set(0,1.05,-1);
      scene.add(mesh);
    });

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();

    return () => {
      // Clean up on component unmount
      document.body.removeChild(renderer.domElement);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div />;
};

export const QThreeJSScene = qwikify$(ThreeJSScene);

import { QThreeJSScene } from '~/components/Banana';


...


<div class="hero-preview-wrapper">
   <QThreeJSScene/>
</div>



Your light intensity is too low.
Try set:
const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 3000, 100, 0.2, 0.5);
spotLight.position.set(0, 25, 0);
scene.add(spotLight);

or set additional light
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(5, 10, 7.5);
scene.add(light);

BTW PointLight or SpotLight are specific lights, always keep in mind its position and intensity (especially when you use Three.js-R>154).

Hi! Thanks for shedding light on the matter. Is there a way to tell what coordinates a specific point on a page will be or just guess and check? After increasing the intensity for whatever reason it seemingly doesn't change no matter where the coordinates are

You can, for example, intersecting objects by Raycaster, and retrieve position in 3D.
